# How to apply a Cloud Mask in Google Earth Engine? (Landsat 5 TM 8-Day NDVI Composite)

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, ndvi, masking, cloud-gis

I need to download ndvi values for some pixels for 2000-2001 using the Landsat 5 TM 8-Day NDVI Composite, but since there is no quality band as in mod13q1 there's no way to filter by quality. Therefore, I want to make a mask using an image collection with information about clouds or shadows so I can mask those pixels with high o low values.
I have the script to download the ndvi values but I don't know how to apply the mask neither how to create the mask..

any experience with that?

Code:

```js
var puntos = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:11qUO03jhF4MiECWgd5Rev536WFERNiqWf5qpqXwb');

var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT5_L1T_8DAY_NDVI').select('NDVI')
                                     .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2000-02-28');


var f_extraer_puntos = function(i){return i.reduceRegions({collection: puntos, reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), scale: 30, })};

// #Extract the values by running reduceRegions over each image in the image collection.
var valores_ = landsat.map(f_extraer_puntos);

var ext_puntos = ee.FeatureCollection(valores_.flatten());
// #Turn the result into a feature collection

Export.table.toDrive({ collection: ext_puntos, description:'LT5_NDVI_puntos', fileFormat: 'CSV' });
```

Comment: And your script is...

Comment: It's just a simple cript to download ndvi values. I didn't try to add anything about the cloud mask yet..

Comment: var puntos = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:11qUO03jhF4MiECWgd5Rev536WFERNiqWf5qpqXwb');

var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT5_L1T_8DAY_NDVI').select('NDVI')
.filterDate('2000-01-01', '2000-02-28');

Comment: var f_extraer_puntos = function(i){return i.reduceRegions({collection: puntos, reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), scale: 30, })};// #Extract the values by running reduceRegions over each image in the image collection.
var valores_ = landsat.map(f_extraer_puntos);
var ext_puntos = ee.FeatureCollection(valores_.flatten());// #Turn the result into a feature collection 
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ext_puntos,
  description:'LT5_NDVI_puntos',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

Comment: Check my answer in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252248/using-landsat-5-tm-8-day-ndvi-composite). In your case, I would use Landsat 5 TM TOA/BOA reflectance, apply a cloud mask and compute NDVI. For [cloud mask check this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271322/cloud-mask-in-surface-reflectance-landsat-8-test/271329#271329)

Comment: thank you so much! how would you apply it to my script?

Answer (score 4):

Your feature collection is private, so I can't apply your code. But, here you have how to mask clouds from Landsat 5 Collection 1 Tier 2 TOA Reflectance and compute NDVI:

```js
var region = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-71.9000244140625, -30.817346256492073],
          [-70.7080078125, -30.826780904779778],
          [-70.6640625, -30.372875188118016],
          [-71.8670654296875, -30.410781790845878]]]),
    landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T2_TOA");

var collection = landsat.filterBounds(region).filterDate('2000-01-01', '2000-02-28');

var getQABits = function(image, start, end, newName) {
    // Compute the bits we need to extract.
    var pattern = 0;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
       pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    // Return a single band image of the extracted QA bits, giving the band
    // a new name.
    return image.select([0], [newName])
                  .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
                  .rightShift(start);
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var cloud_shadows = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['BQA']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 7,8, 'Cloud_shadows');
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

// A function to mask out cloudy pixels.
var clouds = function(image) {
  // Select the QA band.
  var QA = image.select(['BQA']);
  // Get the internal_cloud_algorithm_flag bit.
  return getQABits(QA, 4,4, 'Cloud').neq(1);
  // Return an image masking out cloudy areas.
};

var maskClouds = function(image) {
  var cs = cloud_shadows(image);
  var c = clouds(image);
  image = image.updateMask(cs);
  return image.updateMask(c);
};

var NDVI = function(image) {
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
};

var ndvi = collection.map(maskClouds).map(NDVI);

Map.addLayer(collection, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],min: [0,0,0],max: [0.2, 0.2, 0.2]}, 'Landsat with clouds');
Map.addLayer(ndvi,{min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']}, 'NDVI cloud free');
```

Link to reproducible example: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2602e7e0f67bd31e1f53379dcd326148

You need to check [Landsat documentation](https://landsat.usgs.gov/collectionqualityband) to know how to decode BQA from this collection.

Comment: The link is to an example based on SENTINEL/COPERNICUS, not Landsat.

Comment: @intotecho you are right, thank you. It's fixed now

Comment: NDVI should be ['B4,  'B3'] for Landsat 5, not ['B5', 'B4'].

Comment: @william3031 right, I missed that. It's corrected now