# Filtering clouds and creating median with Google Earth Engine Landsat8 EVI Composite

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, evi

I am downloading images from Google Earth Engine's Landsat 8 Collection 1 Tier 1 8-Day EVI Composite collection [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_8DAY_EVI). I would like to create one image, a median composite of the images from May 1st to August 31st in a year and I would like to filter for clouds.

I want to filter the collection for clouds, however, there is not a cloud tag available in the dataset so the cloud filter function does not work. There's also not a "QA_PIXEL" to filter out for the best pixel. Someone suggested to me that to filter for clouds I could keep the range of EVI values from 0 to 1, as negative values are often associated with clouds, but I'm not sure how accurate that is. The EVI collection itself is already a composite, but I can't find any documentation regarding whether they already filtered for clouds. I have looked through the google earth engine github repository and elsewhere.

Here is the code I have. Does this look like a good way to filter for clouds and obtain the median? Should I put back in the negative values to get a more accurate median?

```
// Define the state shape of California
var california = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2018/States')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'California'));

// Extract the geometry of California
var roi = california.geometry();

// Load Landsat 8
var eviCol = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_EVI") 
  .filterDate('2021-05-01', '2021-08-31')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .select('EVI');

// Create a cloud mask based on 'EVI' values
var cloudMasked = eviCol.map(function(image) {
  var eviThreshold = 0; // Adjust the EVI threshold as needed
  return image.updateMask(image.gte(eviThreshold));
});

// Calculate the median composite from the cloud-masked collection
var medianComposite = cloudMasked.median();

// Visualize the median composite with min set to 0 to mask out negative values
var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0, // Set min to 0 to mask out negative values
  max: 1,
  palette: [
    'ffffff', 'ce7e45', 'df923d', 'f1b555', 'fcd163', '99b718', '74a901',
    '66a000', '529400', '3e8601', '207401', '056201', '004c00', '023b01',
    '012e01', '011d01', '011301'
  ],
};
Map.addLayer(medianComposite.clip(roi), colorizedVis, 'Cloud-Filtered Median Composite');

// Export the median composite image to Google Drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: medianComposite,
  description: 'Landsat2021California_MedianComposite',
  scale: 30,
  region: roi,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Comment: [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/271493/181131) may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the EVI yourself, from the "plain" Landsat 8 collection. That would give you more control over the cloud masking. Something like this:

```
// Define the state shape of California
var california = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2018/States')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'California'));

// Extract the geometry of California
var roi = california.geometry();
print(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2').first())
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
  .filterDate('2021-05-01', '2021-08-31')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .map(function (image) {
    var rescaled = image
      .select('SR_B.')
      .multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
    var evi = ee.Image()
      .expression(
        'G * ((nir - red) / (nir + C1 * red - C2 * blue + L))', {
          blue: rescaled.select('SR_B3'),
          red: rescaled.select('SR_B4'),
          nir: rescaled.select('SR_B5'),
          i: rescaled,
          L: 1,
          C1: 6,
          C2: 7.5,
          G: 2.5
        }
      )
      .clamp(-1, 1)
    var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL')
    var cloudFree = bitwiseExtract(qa, 6)
    var water = bitwiseExtract(qa, 7)
    return evi
      .updateMask(cloudFree.or(water))
  })

var median = collection
  .median()
  .clip(roi)
  
Map.addLayer(median, {min: 0, max: 1, 
  palette: [
      'ffffff', 'ce7e45', 'df923d', 'f1b555', 'fcd163', '99b718', '74a901',
      '66a000', '529400', '3e8601', '207401', '056201', '004c00', '023b01',
      '012e01', '011d01', '011301'  
  ]
})
Map.centerObject(roi)


function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c4b980e775dbbc5da03e3cc286d0b2e9